# rarefying array with limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have array of objects form AR
I want to rarefy them, with limit.

Current method looks like:

```
  def rarefied_values(limit = 200)
    all_values = self.values.all
    rarefied_values = []

    chunk_size = (all_values.size / limit.to_f).ceil
    if all_values.size > limit
      all_values.each_slice(chunk_size) do |chunk|
        rarefied_values.push(chunk.first)
      end
      return rarefied_values
    else
      return all_values
    end
  end
```

Any hints for refactoring?

Comment: Are you sure that your snippet is correct? Coz 'return rarefied_values' will occur but 'return' never.

Comment: I have edited your code to remove the incorrect indentation, showcasing what @megas was referring to.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "rarefy"? Does your above code perform exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rarefied_values(limit = 200)
  all_values = values.all
  return all_values unless all_values.size > limit
  chunk_size = all_values.size / limit
  (0...limit).map{|i| all_values[i*chunk_size]}
end
```

Some general points in refactoring in ruby

- `self` can be omitted usually. In a few cases, you cannot, for example `self.class`. In this case, `self.values.all` => `values.all`
- If one of the conditioned procedures is much simpler compared to the others, then place that simple case first, and get rid of it from the rest of the code using `return`. In this case, `return all_values unless all_values.size > limit`
- In general, when you need nested conditions, design it so that cases with simpler procedures split off eariler, and the complicated cases are placed toward the end.
- Let the code be lazy as possible. In this case, `rarefied_values = []` is not necessary if `all_values.size > limit`. So put that in the conditioned section.

Comment: (0...(count/all_values.size)).map{|i| all_values[(i*chunk_size+1)]}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naïve refactor, keeping your same methods, but removing the explicit return calls and only performing certain transformations if necessary:

```
def rarefied_values(limit = 200)
  all_values = self.values.all
  if all_values.size <= limit
    all_values
  else
    chunk_size = (all_values.size / limit.to_f).ceil
    [].tap{ |rare| all_values.each_slice(chunk_size){ |c| rare << c.first } }
  end
end
```

Here's a faster, more terse version:

```
def rarefied_values(limit = 200)
  all_values = self.values.all      
  if (size = all_values.size) <= limit
    all_values
  else
    all_values.values_at(*0.step(size-1,(size.to_f/limit).ceil))
  end
end
```